# как лучше сказать: провела этот день с тобой или посвятила его тебе?

Tags: недопустимая-метка

как лучше/корректнее сказать: провела с тобой этот день или посвятила его тебе?

Answer (score 0):

Различие сугубо стилистическое. Вариант "Посвятила..." имеет возвышенный оттенок. "Аркадий, не говори красиво."